# (/home/user/.sbt) has been deprecated. Please use the standard location: /home/user/project?

Tags: scala, sbt

When I start the `sbt console` I get this:

> alex@alex-K43U:~$ sbt console [warn] Alternative project directory
>   .sbt (/home/alex/.sbt) has been deprecated since sbt 0.12.0. [warn]
>   Please use the standard location: /home/alex/project [info] Loading
>   project definition from /home/alex/.sbt [info] Set current project to
>   default-22b2b7 (in build file:/home/alex/)

I just started using scala and sbt, so I'm not really sure what the warning means. It means that I have to move all the content of `/home/alex/.sbt` to `/home/alex/project`?

(I have this folder too: `/home/alex/sbt` which has a `bin` folder and a `jansi-license.txt` file. I think that's how I installed sbt).

Comment: You should probably not run `sbt` from your `$HOME` but create a dedicated project folder (which would have its very own `project/` subdirectory) first.

Comment: @Debilski Thanks, can you post a answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 6):

You can run sbt from any dedicated folder besides your home to get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 2):

This warn appears because you run sbt from the directory that contains the `.sbt` folder, that in your case is `/home/alex/.sbt`

Create a folder (named `project` or something else) inside `/home/alex/` and run sbt from there. Don't move the `.sbt` data inside the new folder because the warn will appear again.